# Rotations in splay trees

Tags: data-structures, trees, splay-trees

I am having some difficulties splaying the element 4 to the root. 
Considering the following splay tree.

```
0
 \
  1
   \
    2
     \
      3
       \
        4
```

Could anyone show me the steps how to get the 4 to the root?

Comment: Strange title? Have a look at [splay trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) and their rotations at wikipedia. Then tell us what you don't understand.

Comment: Sorry not for  expression where the problems lies..

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the algorithm. First you have to do a *zag-zag-rotation*, which gives you

```
0
 \
  1
   \
    4
   / 
  3    
 /      
2
```

Then you have to do another *zag-zag-rotation* and you obtain as the result of **splay(4)** the tree

```
    4
   / 
  1   
 / \ 
0   3      
   /  
  2
```

Comment: That's also how i Imagined it would look like, but I have a hard time understanding how the rotations from the first to the second is performed..

Comment: Just follow the rules (see wikipedia) and keep the subtrees hanging off the three nodes that are involved fixed.